# document.queryselectorall not working on multiple classes javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What I was trying to do  a group of elements having same class I wanted to iterate over them and add some classes or do some task but document.querySelectorAll() is not working even it is returning the node list length 0
so anyone can help me with this I am stuck at this point.

Js Script

```
<script>
        var highlightedItems = document.querySelectorAll(".highlighted");

        highlightedItems.forEach(function (userItem) {
            deleteUser(userItem);
        });

        console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.headings'));
        if (document.querySelectorAll('.headings').length === 0) {
            //do stuff
            console.log("hello it is working");
        }
        document.querySelectorAll('.headings').forEach(item => {
            console.log("it is not good but its okay");

            item.addEventListener('click', event => {
                console.log('hello');
            })
        })

    </script>
```

even I tried to check the length with if condition and it is showing 0

html divs

```
    <p class="highlighted">hello heloo helllo</p>
    <p class="highlighted">hello heloo helllo</p>
    <p class="highlighted">hello heloo helllo</p>
    <p class="highlighted">hello heloo helllo</p>
    <h1 class="animate__animated animate__bounce"> heloo</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings">An animated element</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings">An animated element</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings">An animated element</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings">An animated element</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>
    <h1 class="mheadings animate__animated animate__bounce">An animated element</h1>
```

Comment: Probably the usual problem, that your script code runs before the elements actually exist …? Place the script element after those elements in the HTML, or make your code execute on document ready.

Comment: Or simply the typo: `'headings' !== 'mheadings'`

Comment: its not about headings!==mheading i was just changing the class names

Comment: Then you need to provide a valid example html and js, ideally in a snippet.   Giving us something with *obvious* typos will only lead us to assume it's obviously the obvious typos causing your problem.

Comment: Your code, *as presented* (minus the alleged typo) works perfectly  https://jsfiddle.net/6zd18j9x/ (in jsfiddle the code always runs after the DOM, so if it's not working for you, check the first comment here and/or wrap it in doc.ready (as you originally tagged as [jquery]))

Comment: yes thanks for the help first comment did help thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.headings` to select elements but your HTML elements has `mheading` class

To fix it: change your class name to `mheading` in the selector function or to `heading` in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

For using queryselectorall you will need to use the tagName.className.

In your case kindly try -

```
document.querySelectorAll('p.highlighted')
```

or

```
document.querySelectorAll('h1.mheadings')
```

Also, Kindly refer to the right class names as i do not find the mentioned class by you in the code.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to include the tag name